# Auto-alter data when not compatible in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, alter

I'm trying to create a movie databse in MYSQL (I use MYSQL workbench).

I use TxtToMy [(link)](http://www.withdata.com/txttomy.html) to import the ratings.csv-file generated by imdb.com into MYSQL.

Now the problem is that 16 movies (out of 819) can not be imported because the 'date_released' is not in the correct format.

This error shows in the log:

> (#22007) Incorrect date value: '1983-05' for column 'release_date' at row 1

Now I wonder if there is way to alter the table in MYSQL to automatically change any date in the format YYYY-MM to YYYY-MM-DD with DD being 00 or something. Or so that is also accepts dates in different formats.

Comment: just edit by hand the csv and you're done. If the file is regularily generated, make a small script using a regexp to change the broken dates. I don't think this should be put in Mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `TxtToMy` very well, but if you have to use it, *and* if it won't allow you to implement a solution like didierc proposed above, then one option would be to add a VARCHAR column for importing the raw date and use a trigger to update the "real" date column.

Assuming your table is named `MOVIES`...

```
ALTER TABLE MOVIES ADD (RawDateFromIMDB VARCHAR(10));
```

Then change your `TxtToMy` definition to import into `RawDateFromIMDB` instead of `release_date`.

This trigger will take the raw date and use it to update your `release_date` column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Movie_RawDateParse
  BEFORE INSERT ON Movies
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.release_date = str_to_date(NEW.RawDateFromIMDB, '%Y-%m-%d');
END;
```

MySQL seems perfectly happy to have a date like '1983-05-00' so this worked for me when I "imported" the value `1983-05` into `RawDateFromIMDB`. It also worked for a "regular" date, as you can see below:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Movies (RawDateFromIMDB) values ('1983-05');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Movies (RawDateFromIMDB) values ('1983-06-22');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT release_date, RawDateFromIMDB FROM Movies;
+--------------+-----------------+
| release_date | RawDateFromIMDB |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 1983-05-00   | 1983-05         |
| 1983-06-22   | 1983-06-22      |
+--------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```